Ignore one grid column for centering the complete grid, e.g. with margin-auto
I have the following setup:
A grid container is placed within a wider div element. The grid element has width fit-content.
The grid has columns auto-1fr-auto-1fr. The exact widths of all columns depends on dynamic content and is unknown (the auto columns are quite narrow).
I wish to center the complete grid within the parent container, however, in doing so ignore the first, leftmost column. (i.e. the grid should be placed as if it consisted just of the 1fr-auto-1fr columns).
I'm trying all sorts of things; what gets me the closest seems to be to set the left columns' items' width to 0; however, this fails to account for any spacing between columns 1 and 2 like grid-column-gap.
I wish to avoid anything that adds additional, unused space to the right. (The main reason for this is that fully using the available space should take priority over centering, if the parent div ends up being too narrow.)
Any canonical way to achieve this?
In my example, the v in the middle and the ^below should line up


.parent{
  width: 600px;
  border: black solid 1px;
}

.grid-container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto 1fr;
  margin: auto;
  width: fit-content;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.grid-dummy{
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: CornflowerBlue;
}
.mid-indicator{
  margin: auto;
  width: fit-content;
}
<div class="parent">
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div>1</div>
    <div class="grid-dummy">Just some long content to stretch</div>
    <div> v </div>
    <div class="grid-dummy">Short</div>
        <div>2</div>
    <div class="grid-dummy">Some more</div>
    <div> v </div>
    <div class="grid-dummy">Whatever</div>
  </div>
  <div class="mid-indicator">^
  </div>
</div>




One way to do it would be to have an invisible fifth column which is a replica of the first column.


.parent {
  width: 600px;
  border: black solid 1px;
}

.grid-container { 
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto 1fr auto;
  margin: auto;
  width: fit-content;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.grid-dummy {
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: CornflowerBlue;
}

.grid-container>*:nth-child(5n) {
  color: red;
  opacity: 0.2;
}

.mid-indicator {
  margin: auto;
  width: fit-content;
}
<div class="parent">
  <div class="grid-container">

    <div>1</div>
    <div class="grid-dummy">Just some long content to stretch</div>
    <div>v</div>
    <div class="grid-dummy">Short</div>
    <div>1</div>
    
    <div>2</div>
    <div class="grid-dummy">Some more</div>
    <div>v</div>
    <div class="grid-dummy">Whatever</div>
    <div>2</div>
    
  </div>
  <div class="mid-indicator">^</div>
</div>




Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately, this is at odds with my desire to avoid adding elements to the right which take up actual space (admittedly easy to miss in my original question; added a reasoning to it now to make it clearer.)

In your snippet, your parent element has a fixed width, which means it can never be "too narrow". Are you saying that in your real application it won't have a fixed width?

Yes, sorry for not being explicit there; the parent width may vary (in particular may depend on the viewport). Also, the elements in the fr-columns may grow, making space a potential concern.
